# Is there an option in chart.js to hide values in the graph legend

Tags: c#, asp.net, chart.js

I've picked up a project from a former colleague but know nothing about javascript and/or chart.js, I'm trying to learn.

I've been asked to part of the graph/legend - red ring in the image.

The thing is the chartjs json string/structure is split into separate variables which make it pretty hard to follow - and also give code samples.  I've tried changing the "options" string, i.e. `options: {legend: {display:false }}`, but it's still displaying.

Is the part marked red actually part of the legend or is it something else on the chart

[Image showing what I need to hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPMT2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't the legend. Somewhere in the options there is a property `xAxes`. Here your collegue has defined multiple new axes. These are the ones you see. If you remove them and remove the `xAxisId` from the datasets you will get what you want

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Now I just need to decode his code to figure out where to make the change.

Comment: It took me a while to find where the multiple axes were being generated, but I did, and only run that line of code under certain criteria.  So, once again, thanks for pointing me in the right direction @LeeLenalee